# Extract text from particular elements of a large poorly formatted XML file

Tags: xml, large-files

I have a large (~50Mb) file containing poorly formatted XML describing documents and properties between `<item> </item>` tags, and I want to **extract the text from all English documents**.

Python's standard XML parsing utilities (dom, sax, expat) choke on the bad formatting, and more forgiving libraries (sgmllib, BeautifulSoup) parse the entire file and take too long.

```
<item>
  <title>some title</title>
  <author>john doe</author>
  <lang>en</lang>
  <document> .... </document>
</item>
```

Does anyone know a way to extract text between `<document> </document>` *only if* the `lang=en` without parsing the entire document?

**Additional information:  Why it's "poorly formatted"**

Some of the documents have an attribute `<dc:link></dc:link>` which causes problems with the parsers.  Python's xml.minidom complains:

```
ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 13, column 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by `poorly formatted XML`? Is it an invalid XML? If you have an invalid XML file all parsers will choke and you will need to do the parsing manually.

Comment: What kind of process emits poorly-formed XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have gawk

```
gawk 'BEGIN{
 RS="</item>"
 startpat="<document>"
 endpat="</document>"
 lpat=length(startpat)
 epat=length(endpat)
}
/<lang>en<\/lang>/{
    match($0,"<document>")
    start=RSTART
    match($0,"</document>")
    end=RSTART
    print substr($0,start+lpat,end-(start+lpat)) 
}' file
```

output

```
$ more file
Junk
Junk
<item>
  <title>some title</title>
  <author>john doe</author>
  <lang>en</lang>
  <document> text
         i want blah ............  </document>
</item>
junk
junk
<item>
  <title>some title</title>
  <author>jane doe</author>
  <lang>ch</lang>
  <document> junk text
           ..       ............ </document>
</item>
junk
blahblah..
<item>
  <title>some title</title>
  <author>GI joe</author>
  <lang>en</lang>
  <document>  text i want ..... in one line  </document>
</item>
aksfh
aslkfj
dflkas

$ ./shell.sh
 text
         i want blah ............
  text i want ..... in one line
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly what I was looking for.  Something that doesn't care about the XML convention.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some event oriented parser, like SAX, or in .NET, `System.Xml.XmlReader`;

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how (and how badly) the document is 'broken' it might be possible to write a simple filter in perl/python that fixes it enough to pass XML well-formedness tests and make it into a DOM or XSLT.

Can you add some examples of what's wrong with the input?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Yes, the error was in one of the attributes **ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 13, column 0**

Line 13:

    <dc:link>...</dc:link>


Apparently it's the `dc` namespace.  I'll try to figure out how to bind this...

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are ok with Java, then VTD-XML would work without any issues of those undefined prefixes...